# OpenCV = operator

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on OpenCV and I have a confusion. I went through this [link](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#cv-mat-operator) and I did not quite understand the concept of '=' operator in OpenCV.

Suppose I declare 3 Matrices as follows:

```
Mat img1, img2, gray;
```

If I obtain the matrix `gray` from the image captured from the camera and assign it to `img1` as mentioned below, what actually happens? Does the data in `gray` get copied to `img1` or is it that data is shared between them?

```
img1 = gray;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenCV's `Mat` class is simply a *header* for the actual image data, which it contains a pointer to.  The `=` operator copies the pointer (and the other information in the header, like the image dimensions) so that both `Mat`s share the same data.  This means that modifying the data in one `Mat` also changes it in the other.  This is called a "shallow" copy, since only the top layer (the header) is copied, not the lower layer (the data).

To make a copy of the underlying data (called a "deep copy"), use the `clone()` method.  You can find information about it on the page that you linked to.

Comment: That explains the concept very well. I used the clone() method and my code works like magic. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It explains in the link you provided.

> Mat& Mat::operator = (const Mat& m)
>
> m :The assigned, right-hand-side matrix. Matrix assignment is O(1) operation, that is, **no data is copied**. Instead, the **data is shared** and the reference counter, if any, is incremented. Before assigning new data, the old data is dereferenced via Mat::release .

Comment: How can copy the data to img1 from gray?