# Real-time template matching - OpenCV, C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, template-matching

I am trying to implement real-time tracking using templates. I wish to update the template with every frame. The main modifications I have done are:

1) separated the template matching and minmaxLoc into separate modules namely, **TplMatch()** and **minmax()** functions, respectively.

2) Inside the **track()** function, the select_flag is kept always true so that new template is copied to 'myTemplate' with every iteration.

3) The last 3 lines of function **track()** are to update the template (roiImg).

4) **Also,** I have removed any arguments to **track()** function, since, **img** and **roiImg** are global variables and hence no need to pass them to functions.

Following is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

#include <sstream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Point point1, point2; /* vertical points of the bounding box */
int drag = 0;
Rect rect; /* bounding box */
Mat img, roiImg; /* roiImg - the part of the image in the bounding box */
int select_flag = 0;
bool go_fast = false;

Mat mytemplate;


///------- template matching -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Mat TplMatch( Mat &img, Mat &mytemplate )
{
  Mat result;

  matchTemplate( img, mytemplate, result, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED );
  normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  return result;
}


///------- Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Point minmax( Mat &result )
{
  double minVal, maxVal;
  Point  minLoc, maxLoc, matchLoc;

  minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );
  matchLoc = minLoc;

  return matchLoc;
}


///------- tracking --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void track()
{
    if (select_flag)
    {
        roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
//         select_flag = false;
        go_fast = true;
    }

//     imshow( "mytemplate", mytemplate ); waitKey(0);

    Mat result  =  TplMatch( img, mytemplate );
    Point match =  minmax( result ); 

    rectangle( img, match, Point( match.x + mytemplate.cols , match.y + mytemplate.rows ), CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), 0.5 );

    std::cout << "match: " << match << endl;

    /// latest match is the new template
    Rect ROI = cv::Rect( match.x, match.y, mytemplate.cols, mytemplate.rows );
    roiImg = img( ROI );
    imshow( "roiImg", roiImg ); //waitKey(0);
}


///------- MouseCallback function ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && !drag)
    {
        /// left button clicked. ROI selection begins
        point1 = Point(x, y);
        drag = 1;
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && drag)
    {
        /// mouse dragged. ROI being selected
        Mat img1 = img.clone();
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rectangle(img1, point1, point2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3, 8, 0);
        imshow("image", img1);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP && drag)
    {
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rect = Rect(point1.x, point1.y, x - point1.x, y - point1.y);
        drag = 0;
        roiImg = img(rect);
//  imshow("MOUSE roiImg", roiImg); waitKey(0);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        /// ROI selected
        select_flag = 1;
        drag = 0;
    }

}



///------- Main() ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    int k;
/*    
///open webcam
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
      return 1;*/

    ///open video file
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open( "Megamind.avi" );
    if ( !cap.isOpened() )
    {   cout << "Unable to open video file" << endl;    return -1;    }
/*    
    /// Set video to 320x240
     cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
     cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);*/

    cap >> img;
    GaussianBlur( img, img, Size(7,7), 3.0 );
    imshow( "image", img );

    while (1)
    {
        cap >> img;
        if ( img.empty() )
            break;

    // Flip the frame horizontally and add blur
    cv::flip( img, img, 1 );
    GaussianBlur( img, img, Size(7,7), 3.0 );

        if ( rect.width == 0 && rect.height == 0 )
            cvSetMouseCallback( "image", mouseHandler, NULL );
        else
            track();

        imshow("image", img);
//  waitKey(100);   k = waitKey(75);
    k = waitKey(go_fast ? 30 : 10000);
        if (k == 27)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The updated template is not being tracked. I am not able to figure out why this is happening since I am updating my template (roiImg) with each iteration. The **match** value from **minmax()** function is returning the same point (coordinates) every-time. Test video is availbale at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpnkk7N2E0Q&feature=youtu.be
Please look into it and guide ahead...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I get your original code from this revision of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20180073/3

I made the smallest change to your original code, my resulting code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

#include <sstream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Point point1, point2; /* vertical points of the bounding box */
int drag = 0;
Rect rect; /* bounding box */
Mat img, roiImg; /* roiImg - the part of the image in the bounding box */
int select_flag = 0;
bool go_fast = false;

Mat mytemplate;


///------- template matching -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Mat TplMatch( Mat &img, Mat &mytemplate )
{
  Mat result;

  matchTemplate( img, mytemplate, result, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED );
  normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  return result;
}


///------- Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Point minmax( Mat &result )
{
  double minVal, maxVal;
  Point  minLoc, maxLoc, matchLoc;

  minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );
  matchLoc = minLoc;

  return matchLoc;
}


///------- tracking --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void track()
{
    if (select_flag)
    {
        //roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
//         select_flag = false;
        go_fast = true;
    }

//     imshow( "mytemplate", mytemplate ); waitKey(0);

    Mat result  =  TplMatch( img, mytemplate );
    Point match =  minmax( result ); 

    rectangle( img, match, Point( match.x + mytemplate.cols , match.y + mytemplate.rows ), CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), 0.5 );

    std::cout << "match: " << match << endl;

    /// latest match is the new template
    Rect ROI = cv::Rect( match.x, match.y, mytemplate.cols, mytemplate.rows );
    roiImg = img( ROI );
    roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
    imshow( "roiImg", roiImg ); //waitKey(0);
}


///------- MouseCallback function ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && !drag)
    {
        /// left button clicked. ROI selection begins
        point1 = Point(x, y);
        drag = 1;
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && drag)
    {
        /// mouse dragged. ROI being selected
        Mat img1 = img.clone();
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rectangle(img1, point1, point2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3, 8, 0);
        imshow("image", img1);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP && drag)
    {
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rect = Rect(point1.x, point1.y, x - point1.x, y - point1.y);
        drag = 0;
        roiImg = img(rect);
        roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
//  imshow("MOUSE roiImg", roiImg); waitKey(0);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        /// ROI selected
        select_flag = 1;
        drag = 0;
    }

}



///------- Main() ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    int k;
/*    
///open webcam
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
      return 1;*/

    ///open video file
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open( "Megamind.avi" );
    if ( !cap.isOpened() )
    {   cout << "Unable to open video file" << endl;    return -1;    }
/*    
    /// Set video to 320x240
     cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
     cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);*/

    cap >> img;
    GaussianBlur( img, img, Size(7,7), 3.0 );
    imshow( "image", img );

    while (1)
    {
        cap >> img;
        if ( img.empty() )
            break;

    // Flip the frame horizontally and add blur
    cv::flip( img, img, 1 );
    GaussianBlur( img, img, Size(7,7), 3.0 );

        if ( rect.width == 0 && rect.height == 0 )
            cvSetMouseCallback( "image", mouseHandler, NULL );
        else
            track();

        imshow("image", img);
//  waitKey(100);   k = waitKey(75);
    k = waitKey(go_fast ? 30 : 10000);
        if (k == 27)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBCopeneCos shows a test of the above program.

I would avoid the use of global variable because I think they do not help in understanding where the problems lie; furthermore I also would pay attention to the shallow vs deep copy for OpenCV's `Mat` class, as [1''](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1397061/1) wrote in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154264/15485):

> OpenCV's `Mat` class is simply a header for the actual image data,
>   which it contains a pointer to. The `operator=` copies the pointer
>   (and the other information in the header, like the image dimensions)
>   so that both Mats share the same data. This means that modifying the
>   data in one Mat also changes it in the other. This is called a
>   "shallow" copy, since only the top layer (the header) is copied, not
>   the lower layer (the data).
>
> To make a copy of the underlying data (called a "deep copy"), use the
>   `clone()` method. You can find information about it on the page that
>   you linked to.

**Edit about the drift:**
In comment [Real-time template matching - OpenCV, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180073/real-time-template-matching-opencv-c/20451941#comment30625850_20451941), [learner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2346085/learner) asks about the tracking drift. 
Looking at the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBCopeneCos we see that at the beginning of the video the program is tracking the girl's right eye while at 0:15 it starts to track the girl's eyebrows, at 0:19 it starts to track the boy's eyebrows and it never tracks anymore the girl's eye, for example at 0:27 it tracks the girl's right eyebrow while the girl's right eye is clearly visible in the image.

This drift from tracking the eye to tracking the eyebrow is normal in a simple code as the one I posted and the explanation is quite simple: see the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGHEu3u9XvI, the video starts with the tracking (contents of the black rectangle) of the playing card, then I remove the playing card from the scene and the tracking black rectangle "drifts" to the bottom left of the scene; after all we are continuosly updating the template and so the behavior is correct: the program stops to track the playing card and starts to track a white background and so you have the "drift"... in other words, your `TplMatch()` function will always return a valid `result` image and your current implementation of `minmax()` will always return a valid a minimum.

Comment: Thanks for you time and guiding me...it works well. Somehow there is some drift coming in, but I would try and look into handling it. I know this drift is inherent with frequent template update...

What is meant by shallow vs deep copy for OpenCV's Mat class?

Comment: @learner http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shallow+deep+opencv Quoting from http://stackoverflow.com/a/18154264/15485 OpenCV's Mat class is simply a header for the actual image data, which it contains a pointer to. The = operator copies the pointer so that both Mats share the same data. This means that modifying the data in one Mat also changes it in the other. This is called a "shallow" copy, since only the top layer (the header) is copied, not the lower layer (the data).

To make a copy of the underlying data ("deep copy"), use the clone() method.

Comment: @learner What do you mean with "drift"? Is it visible in the video I posted?

Comment: Thanks again mate! And, yes, looking at first 15-16 seconds of the video, the box drawn on the eye seems to move towards forehead. Also,  I read somewhere that this drift is an inherent problem with frequent template update. Although, I am yet to find a reason for it. I was thinking it should be more accurate since we update template at every frame thus overcoming the dynamic appearance changes. What do you say??

Comment: @learner I updated the answer with my explanation of the drift.

Comment: I want to select ROI from any frame and not from the first frame only. How can I do that. I am stuck at the condition for this.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson: can you please give some suggestions on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072000/opencv4android-template-matching-using-camera)

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the OpenCV tutorial ["Template Matching"](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html). Your `track` function may contain the code to find the template in the current frame; a simple code is based on the [`matchTemplate`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate) and [`minMaxLoc`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=minmaxloc#minmaxloc) functions.

The interesting issue related to the "real-time" part of your question is to succeed in finding the match, if present, within the time between the current frame and the next one.

**Edit**:

The following quick-and-dirty code and the video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpnkk7N2E0Q&feature=youtu.be shows what I mean for *tracking*.

Since I do not have a webcam I slightly modified your code to just use a video, this one https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/export/7237/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/HighGUI/video-input-psnr-ssim/video/Megamind.avi

I then add `track` function and some logic to slow down the video until I choose a ROI and after that playing the video at normal speed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

#include <sstream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Point point1, point2; /* vertical points of the bounding box */
int drag = 0;
Rect rect; /* bounding box */
Mat img, roiImg; /* roiImg - the part of the image in the bounding box */
int select_flag = 0;
bool go_fast = false;

Mat mytemplate;

void track(cv::Mat &img, const cv::Mat &templ, const cv::Rect &r )
{
    static int n = 0;

    if (select_flag)
    {
        templ.copyTo(mytemplate);
        select_flag = false;
        go_fast = true;
    }


    cv::Mat result;
    /// Do the Matching and Normalize
    matchTemplate( img, mytemplate, result, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED );
    normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    /// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
    double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
    Point matchLoc;

    minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );
    matchLoc = minLoc;

    rectangle( img, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + mytemplate.cols , matchLoc.y + mytemplate.rows ), CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), 3 );

    std::cout << matchLoc << "\n";
}

///MouseCallback function

void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && !drag)
    {
        /* left button clicked. ROI selection begins */
        point1 = Point(x, y);
        drag = 1;
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && drag)
    {
        /* mouse dragged. ROI being selected */
        Mat img1 = img.clone();
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rectangle(img1, point1, point2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3, 8, 0);
        imshow("image", img1);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP && drag)
    {
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rect = Rect(point1.x, point1.y, x - point1.x, y - point1.y);
        drag = 0;
        roiImg = img(rect);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        /* ROI selected */
        select_flag = 1;
        drag = 0;
    }

}


///Main function

int main()
{
    int k;
    /*
        VideoCapture cap(0);
        if (!cap.isOpened())
        return 1;
    */
    VideoCapture cap;
    //cap.open("~/Downloads/opencv-2.4.4/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/HighGUI/video-input-psnr-ssim/video/Megamind.avi");
    cap.open("./Megamind.avi");
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        printf("Unable to open video file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /*
        // Set video to 320x240
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
        */

    cap >> img;
    imshow("image", img);

    while (1)
    {
        cap >> img;
        if (img.empty())
            break;

        if (rect.width == 0 && rect.height == 0)
            cvSetMouseCallback("image", mouseHandler, NULL);
        else
            track(img, roiImg, rect);

        if (select_flag == 1)
            imshow("Template", roiImg);

        imshow("image", img);
        k = waitKey(go_fast ? 30 : 10000);
        if (k == 27)
            break;

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did try matchTemplate() function with "CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED" measure. But I am not getting desired tracking...

Comment: @learner I do not understand, what do you mean with "tracking"?

Comment: when i tried the matchTemplate() function, the result was just a window (of the size of rectangle I drag with mouse) and it shows the webcam feed corresponding to that region...it is tough to explain like this...

could you please suggest a sample code how to go ahead?

Comment: @learner as I wrote in the answer, this tutorial contains a sample code: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Comment: I have tried that already. I am getting the image and the template. All I need is to track it...just getting stuck there :(

Comment: @learner please see the answer, I have updated it in order to show what I mean for tracking.

Comment: ohh! I didn't notice the answer! sorry!
trying to understand it...thanks!

Comment: hey, i tried to update my template with every frame. I have edited the code above (I was trying to BOLD it but didn't happen). So, the edits are just after the **if(select_flag)** part and before the **cout<<matchLoc<<endl;**

It is not updating as I thought...the matchLoc value always remains the same. Why is it happening so?? Whats wrong?

Thank you for your time...

Comment: @learner Hello, I did not see your edit to my code (the revisions of my answers are here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20180256/revisions)

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question with the modifications. Please look at it. I am not able to know where I am doing fault...it should work because I am updating the template everytime.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a general introduction to the subject starting from this wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_tracking