# Template Matching with template update

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, template-matching

I am trying to implement real-time tracking using templates in OpenCV/C++. I am facing problem to update the template with every frame.

Following is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

#include <sstream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Point point1, point2; /* vertical points of the bounding box */
int drag = 0;
Rect rect; /* bounding box */
Mat img, roiImg; /* roiImg - the part of the image in the bounding box */
int select_flag = 0;
bool go_fast = false;

Mat mytemplate;


///------- template matching -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Mat TplMatch( Mat &img, Mat &mytemplate )
{
  Mat result;

  matchTemplate( img, mytemplate, result, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED );
  normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  return result;
}


///------- Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Point minmax( Mat &result )
{
  double minVal, maxVal;
  Point  minLoc, maxLoc, matchLoc;

  minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );
  matchLoc = minLoc;

  return matchLoc;
}


///------- tracking --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void track()
{
    if (select_flag)
    {
        roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
//         select_flag = false;   //select_flag is kept false so that new template can
        go_fast = true;           //copied to 'mytemplate' for each iteration
    }

//     imshow( "mytemplate", mytemplate ); waitKey(0);

    Mat result  =  TplMatch( img, mytemplate );
    Point match =  minmax( result );  //PROBLEM: "match" always returning same value!!!

    rectangle( img, match, Point( match.x + mytemplate.cols , match.y + mytemplate.rows ), CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), 0.5 );

    std::cout << "match: " << match << endl;

    /// template update step
    Rect ROI = cv::Rect( match.x, match.y, mytemplate.cols, mytemplate.rows );
    roiImg = img( ROI );
    imshow( "roiImg", roiImg ); //waitKey(0);
}


///------- MouseCallback function ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && !drag)
    {
        /// left button clicked. ROI selection begins
        point1 = Point(x, y);
        drag = 1;
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && drag)
    {
        /// mouse dragged. ROI being selected
        Mat img1 = img.clone();
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rectangle(img1, point1, point2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3, 8, 0);
        imshow("image", img1);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP && drag)
    {
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rect = Rect(point1.x, point1.y, x - point1.x, y - point1.y);
        drag = 0;
        roiImg = img(rect);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        /// ROI selected
        select_flag = 1;
        drag = 0;
    }

}



///------- Main() ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    int k;

    ///open video file
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open( "Megamind.avi" );
    if ( !cap.isOpened() )
    {   cout << "Unable to open video file" << endl;    return -1;    }

    cap >> img;
    GaussianBlur( img, img, Size(7,7), 3.0 );
    imshow( "image", img );

    while (1)
    {
        cap >> img;
        if ( img.empty() )
            break;

        // Flip the frame horizontally and add blur
        cv::flip( img, img, 1 );
        GaussianBlur( img, img, Size(7,7), 3.0 );

        if ( rect.width == 0 && rect.height == 0 )
            cvSetMouseCallback( "image", mouseHandler, NULL );
        else
            track();

        imshow("image", img);
        k = waitKey(go_fast ? 30 : 10000);
        if (k == 27)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The updated template is not being tracked. I am not able to figure out why this is happening since I am updating my template (roiImg) with each iteration. The **match** value from **minmax()** function is returning the same value (coordinates) every-time. Test video is availbale at: [Megamind](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/export/7237/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/HighGUI/video-input-psnr-ssim/video/Megamind.avi)
Please look into it and guide ahead...thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** if you run the code (with the video) you will see the white bounding-box is always at the same position. This is because, the minmax() is returning same "match" value all the time. This value should change with every update.
Try running code with **select_flag = false;** (uncommitted). The bounding-box is moving according to template. But in this case no template update takes place.

Comment: is this youtube video the input or the output of your program? Can the problem be seen in the video? Looks like the output (since something is tracked), but I'm a bit confused =)
If it is the output, where can I find the input video and was it computed with **select_flag** being true or false?

Comment: @Micka thats the input video. There is nothing tracked in it...

Comment: The red/white rectangle looks like tracking (or trying to track) the "eye".
I would try your program but I don't want to convert the youtube video before doing so.

Comment: @Micka convert what? thats a download link, its hardly a minute's video. the white bounding box appears only if you run the code with the video. you have to choose the initial bounding box with mouse.

Comment: I am talking about your posted youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpnkk7N2E0Q
I see a red/white box around the (marked) eye.
Maybe you uploaded the wrong video?!?

Comment: @Micka aah ok! sorry for dt! please find the video at: https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/export/7237/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/HighGUI/video-input-psnr-ssim/video/Megamind.avi

Comment: Found the video already, didn't know that there was an original posting of yours (linked in the youtube video).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180073/real-time-template-matching-opencv-c

But I've got no time left today... hope I'll find some time on monday to test your code!

Comment: @Micka yeah...wasn't getting much response there. I am sure its a minor design issue that I am not able to figure out! The template is getting updated every-time (last 3 lines of track() function) but the minmax() isn't getting updated somehow...hope u can find something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this section:

```
if (select_flag)
{
    roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
    // select_flag = false;   //select_flag is kept false so that new template can
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^ WRONG
    go_fast = true;           //copied to 'mytemplate' for each iteration
}
```

You actually need to set `select_flag` to be `false` on the first iteration. Otherwise, you're just copying what's in the current image on that frame into your template, and of course you find it in exactly the same place!

Once that's done, make sure you move your template update to *after* the tracking is done on that frame. I'd also recommend not drawing on the original image (your `rectangle`) until after all image accesses are done. You were actually drawing the rectangle into your image before copying out of it. Here's my adjusted function with template update:

```
void track()
{
  std::cout << select_flag << std::endl;

    if (select_flag)
    {
        roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
        select_flag = false;   //select_flag is kept false so that new template can
        go_fast = true;           //copied to 'mytemplate' for each iteration

    }

//     imshow( "mytemplate", mytemplate ); waitKey(0);

    Mat result  =  TplMatch( img, mytemplate );

    imshow("match", result);

    Point match =  minmax( result );  //PROBLEM: "match" always returning same value!!!

    std::cout << "match: " << match << endl;

    /// template update step
    Rect ROI = cv::Rect( match.x, match.y, mytemplate.cols, mytemplate.rows );

    std::cout << ROI << std::endl;

    roiImg = img( ROI );
    imshow( "roiImg", roiImg ); //waitKey(0);

    // Update the template AFTER tracking has occurred to carry it over to the next frame
    roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
    imshow("mytemplate", mytemplate);

    // Draw onto the image AFTER all accesses are performed
    rectangle( img, match, Point( match.x + mytemplate.cols , match.y + mytemplate.rows ), CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), 0.5 );
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i knew i was making a mistake in structure of code!!! nice explanation as well...now the mistake is clear...

Comment: i am trying to restrict the search area for template. Instead of searching the entire image, may be some area around the template should be searched. That would be better. Any idea how to do that? 
I tried something like:
    
    Rect search_region = cv::Rect(0, 0, img.cols, (img.rows/2));
    Mat img2 = img(search_region);
    
and then the template match is done with:
'matchTemplate( img2, mytemplate, result, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED );'
'normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat()'

But, I am not able to make out how it will affect "result"? How to proceed?

Comment: I'd recommend you create another question describing your problem instead of commenting on this one.