# Regarding a specific Object Detection in OpenCV using WebCam and comparing it with an input Image

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, face-recognition, object-detection, haar-classifier

I am new to OpenCV and want to develop a program which takes the camera input and compares it with a known image of an object which would be input to it as a .jpg image and if the input of the Webcam matches with the fed in image upto a certain level of accuracy, then some message etc should be displayed that the required object has been found. 
Eg: If I get a Computer Cable before the webcam, it needs to be detected and compared to the image of the Computer cable I have fed into the program.

I've tried many techniques and find Template matching to be effective as mentioned in the foll0wing link---
[Real-time template matching - OpenCV, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180073/real-time-template-matching-opencv-c)

However after drawing the rectangle and getting the roiImage..I want to compare its likeliness with a known image on my disk(in the opencv working directory). For this I am trying to convert the roiImg and my other images in HSV format and get 4 values according to the Algorithms.

I have tried to combine the 2 codes but it doesn;t seem to work as roiImg is being made at runtime and is not being able to compare with the other 2 Images using imread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

#include <sstream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Point point1, point2; /* vertical points of the bounding box */
int drag = 0;
Rect rect; /* bounding box */
Mat img, roiImg; /* roiImg - the part of the image in the bounding box */
int select_flag = 0;
bool go_fast = false;

Mat mytemplate;
Mat src_base, hsv_base;
Mat src_test1, hsv_test1;
Mat src_test2, hsv_test2;
Mat hsv_half_down;


///------- template matching -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Mat TplMatch( Mat &img, Mat &mytemplate )
{
  Mat result;

  matchTemplate( img, mytemplate, result, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED );
  normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  return result;
}


///------- Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Point minmax( Mat &result )
{
  double minVal, maxVal;
  Point  minLoc, maxLoc, matchLoc;

  minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );
  matchLoc = minLoc;

  return matchLoc;
}


///------- tracking --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void track()
{
    if (select_flag)
    {
        //roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
//         select_flag = false;
        go_fast = true;
    }

//     imshow( "mytemplate", mytemplate ); waitKey(0);

    Mat result  =  TplMatch( img, mytemplate );
    Point match =  minmax( result ); 

    rectangle( img, match, Point( match.x + mytemplate.cols , match.y + mytemplate.rows ), CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), 0.5 );

    std::cout << "match: " << match << endl;

    /// latest match is the new template
    Rect ROI = cv::Rect( match.x, match.y, mytemplate.cols, mytemplate.rows );
    roiImg = img( ROI );
    roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
    imshow( "roiImg", roiImg ); //waitKey(0);

//Compare the roiImg with a know image to calculate resemblence 

/*Method    Base - Base Base - Half Base - Test 1   Base - Test 2

Correlation     1.000000    0.930766    0.182073    0.120447
Chi-square      0.000000    4.940466    21.184536   49.273437
Intersection    24.391548   14.959809   3.889029    5.775088
Bhattacharyya   0.000000    0.222609    0.646576    0.801869

For the Correlation and Intersection methods, the higher the metric, the more accurate the match. As we can see, 
the match base-base is the highest of all as expected. Also we can observe that the match base-half is the second best match (as we predicted). 
For the other two metrics, the less the result, the better the match. We can observe that the matches between the test 1 and test 2 with respect
to the base are worse, which again, was expected.)*/


    src_base = imread("roiImg");
    src_test1 = imread("Samarth.jpg");
    src_test2 = imread("Samarth2.jpg");
    //double l2_norm = cvNorm( src_base, src_test1 );

    /// Convert to HSV
    cvtColor( src_base, hsv_base, COLOR_BGR2HSV );
    cvtColor( src_test1, hsv_test1, COLOR_BGR2HSV );
    cvtColor( src_test2, hsv_test2, COLOR_BGR2HSV );

    hsv_half_down = hsv_base( Range( hsv_base.rows/2, hsv_base.rows - 1 ), Range( 0, hsv_base.cols - 1 ) );

    /// Using 50 bins for hue and 60 for saturation
    int h_bins = 50; int s_bins = 60;
    int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins };

    // hue varies from 0 to 179, saturation from 0 to 255
    float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
    float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };

    const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges };

    // Use the o-th and 1-st channels
    int channels[] = { 0, 1 };


    /// Histograms
    MatND hist_base;
    MatND hist_half_down;
    MatND hist_test1;
    MatND hist_test2;

    /// Calculate the histograms for the HSV images
    calcHist( &hsv_base, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_base, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
    normalize( hist_base, hist_base, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    calcHist( &hsv_half_down, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_half_down, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
    normalize( hist_half_down, hist_half_down, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    calcHist( &hsv_test1, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_test1, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
    normalize( hist_test1, hist_test1, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    calcHist( &hsv_test2, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_test2, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
    normalize( hist_test2, hist_test2, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    /// Apply the histogram comparison methods
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        int compare_method = i;
        double base_base = compareHist( hist_base, hist_base, compare_method );
        double base_half = compareHist( hist_base, hist_half_down, compare_method );
        double base_test1 = compareHist( hist_base, hist_test1, compare_method );
        double base_test2 = compareHist( hist_base, hist_test2, compare_method );

        printf( " Method [%d] Perfect, Base-Half, Base-Test(1), Base-Test(2) : %f, %f, %f, %f \n", i, base_base, base_half , base_test1, base_test2 );
    }


    printf( "Done \n" );

}


///------- MouseCallback function ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && !drag)
    {
        /// left button clicked. ROI selection begins
        point1 = Point(x, y);
        drag = 1;
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && drag)
    {
        /// mouse dragged. ROI being selected
        Mat img1 = img.clone();
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rectangle(img1, point1, point2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3, 8, 0);
        imshow("image", img1);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP && drag)
    {
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rect = Rect(point1.x, point1.y, x - point1.x, y - point1.y);
        drag = 0;
        roiImg = img(rect);
        roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
//  imshow("MOUSE roiImg", roiImg); waitKey(0);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        /// ROI selected
        select_flag = 1;
        drag = 0;
    }

}



///------- Main() ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    int k;

///open webcam
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
      return 1;

 /*   ///open video file
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open( "Wildlife.wmv" );
    if ( !cap.isOpened() )
    {   cout << "Unable to open video file" << endl;    return -1;    }*/

    /*    
    /// Set video to 320x240
     cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
     cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);*/

    cap >> img;
    GaussianBlur( img, img, Size(7,7), 3.0 );
    imshow( "image", img );

    while (1)
    {
        cap >> img;
        if ( img.empty() )
            break;

    // Flip the frame horizontally and add blur
    cv::flip( img, img, 1 );
    GaussianBlur( img, img, Size(7,7), 3.0 );

        if ( rect.width == 0 && rect.height == 0 )
            cvSetMouseCallback( "image", mouseHandler, NULL );
        else
            track();

        imshow("image", img);
//  waitKey(100);   k = waitKey(75);
    k = waitKey(go_fast ? 30 : 10000);
        if (k == 27)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to detect a object in live feed , detecting the object in each frame is not efficient .. for the first time you have to detect after you have to track the object.
so this process involving both detection and tracking..
for detection you have to segment the object from the rest, opencv provides many algorithms for segmenting an object from background based on colors [color based detection](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html).other than color you can use the objects's shape to segment the object from background[shape based segmentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html).

you can use lk optical flow algorithm as a starting to tracking.

additionally, you can use template matching or camshift or medial flow tracker.. etc to obtain quick results.all the above algorithm will be useful based on scale change of the object  and lighting change of the feed. opencv has sample programs to the above algorithms.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I am planning to use the SURF algorithm, which detects the object present in the image. My next job is to feed have 2 images together and then detect the object to perform a certain task. eg: If i feed the image of the Backside of the CPU and of the Computer Cable, and then bring the actual computer cable in front of the webcam, the program must be able to link the computer cable to the port it has to be inserted in.